# Errors in Data-Transfer due to quotes in column-fields

Tags: database, postgresql, data-transfer, dbeaver

I am trying to do a standard data-transfer from a bunch of tables (from CSV, DB2 and PostGreSQL) into a PostGreSQL-instance. The tool I am using is Dbeaver Light's Data Transfer Task.

However, I am facing a ton of errors and I have tracked it down to being due to the actual content of the data.

What I see in the data are examples like this:
[image]

Resulting in the following error:
[image]

I believe the errors arise due to the " in the data since these are used to qualify colums like so:

SELECT "Column1", "Column2" FROM "schema"."table"

The setting I am using are:
[image]
[image]

Can anyone think of a way to solve this?

Comment: 1) Do not use images to present textual data, copy and paste as text. 2) If you had done 1) I could past what the the issue is. The error is the input is too long for varchar(40) field and it is too long because columns in the file are being combined. 3) You need to update your question with the settings you are using to do the import.

Comment: Updated the Question with the settings I am using. However, I do not believe the solution is to be found here.

Comment: Looking at the picture all the data is the same for every row. Is that supposed to be the case? Or is there a problem in the  table mapping section?

Comment: The data in the picture is from the source table and it is supposed to be like that.

Comment: That seems strange. Still, the issue is two column values are being combined and inserted into one `varchar(40)` and the combined value is too long for the field. I would look at the table/column mapping. Also look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database.